# Flutter - Container BoxShadow disappears on scroll in a ListView

Tags: listview, dart, dropshadow, flutter

This is what my Container looks like:

```
new Container(
        width: 500.0,
        height: 250.0,
        padding: new EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20.0, 40.0, 20.0, 40.0),
        decoration: new BoxDecoration(
          color: const Color(0xFF66BB6A),
          boxShadow: [new BoxShadow(
            color: Colors.black,
            blurRadius: 20.0,
          ),]
        ),
        child: new Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            new Container(
              padding: new EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 10.0),
              child: new Text("Testtext", style: new TextStyle(fontSize: 30.0, fontFamily: "Barrio", color: new Color.fromARGB(255, 230, 230, 230))),
            ),
          ]
        ),
      ),
```

It is inside a ListView with some other Containers. As soon as I start scrolling through the ListView, the shadow just disappears. When loading the view tho, it appears correctly.

Any thoughts on this problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I was trying to reproduce the issue, and I noticed that you didn't put any margin on your Container. Most likely the other items in your `ListView` are covering up your manually drawn shadow because it's being drawn outside the bounds of your `Container`.

I would recommend that you use a [`Card`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/Card-class.html) instead of a container. You can get a natural-looking material shadow using the `elevation` constructor argument. Cards come with some built-in margin, and you can add more by enclosing it in a `Container` if you want. This will give you enough space for the shadow to be visible. You can control the color of the `Card` with the `color` constructor argument.

The corners of a `Card` are slightly rounded. If you don't want rounded corners, you're going to be going off spec from Material design, but you could try enclosing a [`Material`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/Material-class.html) with a `type` of [`MaterialType.canvas`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/MaterialType-class.html) inside a `Container`.

Comment: Yep, the margin was the issue! Thank you very much for explaining the problem... :)

Answer (score 39):

This other answer is for those who need to continue with `Container`:

```dart
Container(
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
    shape: BoxShape.circle, // BoxShape.circle or BoxShape.retangle
    //color: const Color(0xFF66BB6A),
    boxShadow: [BoxShadow(
      color: Colors.grey,
      blurRadius: 5.0,
    ),]
  ),
  child: ...
),
```

Answer (score 5):

After a many tries I solved the problem.

```
// if scroll view overflow on other widget then use ClipRRect With Expanded.

    ClipRRect(
    child: Expanded(
    child: ListView(
    clipBehavior: Clip.none, //add this line inside AnyScrollView or ListView
      children:[
         Container(
             decoration: BoxDecoration(boxShadow: [
                BoxShadow(
                      offset: Offset(2, 2),
                      blurRadius: 12,
                      color: Color.fromRGBO(0, 0, 0, 0.16),
                )
               ]),
             child: Widgets(),
           ),
      ],
    ),
  ),
),
```

I face the same problem and i use this tricks and it's solved.

Answer (score 2):

The best and simple solution would be using `Ink` widget instead of Container in your case, since it will retain the shadow properties on scroll shadow will be visible.

```
new Ink(
        width: 500.0,
        height: 250.0,
        padding: new EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20.0, 40.0, 20.0, 40.0),
        decoration: new BoxDecoration(
          color: const Color(0xFF66BB6A),
          boxShadow: [new BoxShadow(
            color: Colors.black,
            blurRadius: 20.0,
          ),]
        ),
        child: new Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            new Container(
              padding: new EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 10.0),
              child: new Text("Testtext", style: new TextStyle(fontSize: 30.0, fontFamily: "Barrio", color: new Color.fromARGB(255, 230, 230, 230))),
            ),
          ]
        ),
      ),
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set your container as follows to give minimal shadow:

```
Container(
           decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  boxShadow: [
                    BoxShadow(
                      color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.3),
                      blurRadius: 5.0,
                      offset: Offset(0.0, 3.0)
                    ),
                  ],
                  border: Border.all(color: AppColors.borderColor),
                  color: Colors.white,
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0)
                ),
          child: Text("Your desired widget here")  
)
```

Happy Fluttering !